# VBA Timer Class

Tags: vba, excel, timer

So I'm trying to write a timer class in VBA, and all seems well except one thing.

when i call the `Application.OnTime` i am required to provide the recurring function's name, and that function sits inside my timer class hence i dont know how to access it.

i have tried passing the timer instance name into the timer to call the function from it as follows:

```
Application.OnTime pNextTick, pName & ".RestartInterval"
```

where pName is the name of the timer instance outside:

```
Set AutoUpdater = New C_Timer
AutoUpdater.Name = "AutoUpdater"
```

but whatever i do, i receive the following error:

> Cannot run the macro "blablablablablabla.xlsm'!AutoUpdater.RestartInterval'. the macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

macros are not disabled in my case, so i need some help here...

here is my `C_Timer` class so far:

```js
'test module
Public Sub test()
    Set AutoUpdater = New C_Timer
    AutoUpdater.Name = "AutoUpdater"
    AutoUpdater.Interval = "00.00.5"
    AutoUpdater.WhatToRun = "DoSomething"
    AutoUpdater.StartTimer
End Sub

Function DoSomething()
    MsgBox "sdoiigsligsdgoidjh"
End Function

'C_Timer class

Private pWhatToRun As String
Private pInterval As String
Private pName As String
Private pRunning As Boolean
Private pNextTick

Private Function RestartInterval()
    If pWhatToRun <> "" Then
        Application.Run pWhatToRun
        pNextTick = Now + TimeValue(pInterval)
        Application.OnTime pNextTick, pName & ".RestartInterval"
    End If
End Function


Public Function StartTimer() As Boolean
On Error GoTo hell

    If TimeValue(pInterval) > TimeValue("00.00.00") And pName <> "" And pRunning <> True Then
        pNextTick = Now + TimeValue(pInterval)
        Application.OnTime pNextTick, pName & ".RestartInterval"
        pRunning = True
    Else
        GoTo hell
    End If
    Exit Function
hell:
        pRunning = False
        M_Settings.SetStatus "Failed to update"
End Function

Public Function StopTimer() As Boolean
On Error GoTo hell
    If pRunning = True Then
        Application.OnTime pNextTick, "RestartInterval", , False
        pRunning = False
    Else
        GoTo hell
    End If
    Exit Function
hell:
        
End Function

Public Property Get WhatToRun() As String
    WhatToRun = pWhatToRun
End Property
Public Property Let WhatToRun(Value As String)
    pWhatToRun = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Interval() As String
    Interval = pInterval
End Property
Public Property Let Interval(Value As String)
    pInterval = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property
```

**UPDATE:** i ended up using the answer below. here is my full code if anyone wants to use it in the future:

```js
'M_Factory module

Public Function CreateTimer(name As String, interval As String) As C_Timer
    Set newTimer_ = New C_Timer
    newTimer_.name = name
    newTimer_.interval = interval
    Set CreateTimer = newTimer_
End Function

'C_Timer Class

Private pInterval As String
Private pName As String
Private pRunning As Boolean
Private pNextTick

Public Function Process(func)
    If func <> "" Then
        Application.Run func
        pNextTick = Now + TimeValue(pInterval)
        Application.OnTime pNextTick, pName & "_Tick"
    End If
End Function


Public Function StartTimer() As Boolean
On Error GoTo hell

    If TimeValue(pInterval) > TimeValue("00.00.00") And pName <> "" And pRunning <> True Then
        pNextTick = Now + TimeValue(pInterval)
        Application.OnTime pNextTick, pName & "_Tick"
        pRunning = True
    Else
        GoTo hell
    End If
    Exit Function
hell:
        pRunning = False
        M_Settings.SetStatus "Failed to update, close & reopen the document"
End Function

Public Property Get Start() As C_Timer
    StartTimer
    Set Start = Me
End Property

Public Function StopTimer() As Boolean
On Error GoTo hell
    If pRunning = True Then
        Application.OnTime pNextTick, pName & "_Tick", , False
        pRunning = False
    Else
        GoTo hell
    End If
    Exit Function
hell:
        
End Function


Public Property Get interval() As String
    interval = pInterval
End Property
Public Property Let interval(Value As String)
    pInterval = Value
End Property

Public Property Get name() As String
    name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let name(Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property

'test module

Public Timer1 As C_Timer, Timer2 As C_Timer
Public Sub test()
    Set Timer1 = M_Factory.CreateTimer("Timer1", "00.00.01").Start
    Set Timer2 = M_Factory.CreateTimer("Timer2", "00.00.5").Start
End Sub

Public Function Timer1_Tick()
    Timer1.Process "DoSomething"
End Function

Public Function Timer2_Tick()
    Timer2.Process "DoMoreStuff"
End Function

Public Sub stopit()
    Timer1.StopTimer
    Timer2.StopTimer
End Sub

Function DoSomething()
    Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "HH:NN:SS")
End Function

Function DoMoreStuff()
    Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "HH:NN:SS")
End Function
```

Comment: How is `.restartinterval` a method for the class? I see the function, but it doesn't seem to return anything as `restartinterval` - or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Raystafarian its not supposed to return anything, its just supposed to call itself every 'tick', the problem is that i dont know how to make the function reference itself in the `.OnTime` function...

Comment: @Raystafarian maybe if you look at it as a function in a module, that sets an interval with itself as a parameter, thats what im trying to do but i need it to reside inside the C_Timer class. there must be a way...

Comment: in starttimer() use `Application.OnTime pNextTick, Me.RestartInterval` and make restartinterval() public. Change restartinterval's ontime to that as well, but I'm getting stuck in an infinite loop from `restartinterval()`

Comment: @Raystafarian using `Me.RestartInterval` treats it like a function call rather than an argument, therefore it calls itself infinitely. from the reference docs it seems that i must pass a string that contains the function name, hmm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the procedure to be run `OnTime` should probably be a public `Sub` from `standard module`. Have you tried the following?

> Standard module

```
Set AutoUpdater = New C_Timer

Public Sub TriggerUpdater()
    AutoUpdater.InsideMyTimerClass
End Sub
```

> Class C_Timer

```
Application.OnTime pNextTick, "TriggerUpdater"

Public Function InsideMyTimerClass() as Variant
...
End Function
```

Comment: But doesn't it defeat the whole point of having a timer class? If i have multiple timers i wouldn't want to make a separate triggertimer sub for each one of them...

Comment: Actually now that i think about it, it looks similar to .net concept if ill semd the triggerupdate subs name as an event handler into the timer object... ill test it and post back

Comment: @Banana I had a look at your question, that's a nice one but I think in this context doesn't make much sense. I mean, having a class is for having multiple timers; that's fine, but VBA is not multi-threaded so you won't anyway be able to make multiple scheduling (you will have to follow a succession of calls). Moreover, the OnTime method of the Application takes a String (and it does because it cannot manage object references. Passing to it "Autoupdater.Method" will make it understand to look for a module named Autoupdater, there's no way to let it understand you're referencing a run-time obj.

Comment: I think your question is more of a "I'd like to know how to do it", but if you have to stuck to VBA you better create a collection of methods/times and pass them as String into a unique static Application.OnTime method (and unfortunately static methods can only exist in module context in VBA).

Comment: Well, its not for multithreading. The idea of multiple timers is to simplify the application.ontime thing, a start/stop functions make more sense and are easier to use than scheduling an ontime every time. And i do actually think that his concept will work with a small adjustment, like in .net you attach an event handler to an event, here we can attach a string holding the "handler's" name, and the timer will schedule an ontime event using that string. The handler function ofc will need to be created publicly in a module, and its name will be attached to the timer.

Comment: So every timer will have its own function in the public module. The multithreading is not necessary since most tasks that i am going to run will be most likely shorter than the interval of the timer.

Comment: Yes, but in that case I would rather see it better as an array N*2; every row of the array stores (as String) the name of the procedure and the time lapse. Hence, you loop through the array and pass them to the Application.OnTime method for the Application to schedule them. I know this is not the answer to your question, but I fear your approach adds a level of complexity to a simple task that doesn't need this generalization. And even in terms of efficiency, if it was possible, instantiating and initializing N timers is much less efficient in terms of iterations and memory consumption.

Comment: i ended up using this approach, ill post my full timer code in the question for anyone who wants to use it in the future. thanks for your help!